# Correct way to configure gradle plugin extensions with groups of dynamic objects

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write my own gradle plugin and it needs to be able to configure a set of objects - how many of these objects and what they're called is up to the user.

The doco for creating custom gradle plugins with advanced customisability is quite poor.  It mentions `project.container()` method to do this kind of thing, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work in my usecase.

This is an example of my plugin's configuration DSL as it stands:

```
teregrin {
  terraformVersion = '0.6.6'

  root("dev"){
    accessKey = "flobble"
  }

  root("prd"){
  }
}
```

And this is my plugin extension object that allows me to configure it:

```
class TeregrinPluginExtension {
  boolean debug = false
  boolean forceUnzip = false
  String terraformVersion = null

  Set<TeregrinRoot> roots = []

  def root(String name, Closure c){
    def newRoot = new TeregrinRoot(name)
    c.setDelegate(newRoot)
    c()
    roots << newRoot
  }

}
```

The extensions wired up in my plugin in the standard way:

```
 project.extensions.create("teregrin", TeregrinPluginExtension)
```

This works ok, but it's a pretty ugly configuration style, not really in the style of the typical gradle DSL.

How can I change my plugin configuration DSL to be something like this:

```
teregrin {
  terraformVersion = '0.6.6'

  roots {
    dev {
      accessKey = "flobble"
    }

    prd {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gradle way of implementing such DSL is by using [extensions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getExtensions()) and [containers](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#container(java.lang.Class)):

```
apply plugin: SamplePlugin

whatever {
  whateverVersion = '0.6.6'
  conf {
    dev {}
    qa {}
    prod {
      accessKey = 'prod'
    }
  }
}

task printWhatever << {
  println whatever.whateverVersion
  whatever.conf.each { c ->
    println "$c.name -> $c.accessKey"
  }
}

class SamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.extensions.create('whatever', SampleWhatever)
    project.whatever.extensions.conf = project.container(SampleConf)
    project.whatever.conf.all {
      accessKey = 'dev'
    }
  }
}

class SampleWhatever {
  String whateverVersion
}

class SampleConf {
  final String name
  String accessKey

  SampleConf(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

while groovy way of doing implementing such DSL is meta programming - you need to implement `methodMissing` in this particular case. Below is a very simple example that demonstrates how it works:

```
class SomeExtension {
  def devConf = new SomeExtensionConf()

  void methodMissing(String name, args) {

    if ('dev'.equals(name)) {
        def c = args[0]
        c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        c.delegate = devConf
        c()
    } else {
      throw new MissingMethodException("Could not find $name method")
    }
  }

  def getDev() {
    devConf
  }
}

class SomeExtensionConf {
  def accessKey
}

project.extensions.create('some', SomeExtension)

some {
  dev {
    accessKey = 'lol'
  }
}

assert 'lol'.equals(some.dev.accessKey)
```

Of course it has no error checking - so the `args` size and type of each argument need to be validated - it's omitted for the sake of brevity.

Of course there's no need to create a separate class for each configuration (I mean `dev`, `prod`, etc.). Create a single class that holds configuration and store them all in a `Map` where key is configuration name.

You can find a demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33717135).

Comment: Regarding the edit: This is the part where I don't understand how to use Project.container - I want the "roots" element to be inside the "teregrin" element.  Or actually, even better, in your DSL, how would I deal with non-repeating groups like "terraformVersion"?

Comment: Ahhhh - I get it.
It was the "project.whatever.extensions.conf = ..." that I didn't understand.  Thankyou.