# Add arbitrarily named domain objects to a task

Tags: gradle

I am new-ish to Groovy/Gradle, so please forgive me if any of my terminology is wrong.

I am trying to write a plugin for Gradle. What I want is a custom task that can take arbitrary names and create domain objects with those names. Something like this is what I am aiming for:

```groovy
task myTask(type: MyTask) {
    hello {
        myMethod 'my data'
    }
    hiagain {
        myMethod 'other data'
    }
}
```

`hello` and `hiagain` would be the names of each domain object, respectively. I currently only want to do this at the top level, but I could see other use cases where I would have a few possible levels of nesting. There is also the case of having both dynamically named objects like the above, but also having other specific properties and methods on those tasks, but I'm not concerned with that right now.

I tried doing this with `NamedDomainObjectContainer`(Task, Container,:

```groovy
package com.mkobit.gradle

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer
import org.gradle.api.Task

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    NamedDomainObjectContainer<MyContainerData> container

    MyTask() {
        container = project.container(MyContainerData)
    }

    @Override
    Task configure(Closure closure) {
        closure.delegate = container
        closure()
        this
    }

    String getGuy(String name) {
        container.getByName(name).myValue
    }
}
```

---

```groovy
package com.mkobit.gradle

import org.gradle.util.Configurable

class MyContainerData implements Configurable<MyContainerData> {

    String myValue


    public MyContainerData(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    @Override
    MyContainerData configure(Closure closure) {
        closure.delegate = this
        closure()
        this
    }

    void myMethod(String s) {
        myValue = s
    }
}
```

---

```groovy
package com.mkobit.gradle

import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTaskTest extends Specification {
    def project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()

    def "name test"() {
        given:
        def task = project.task('myTask', type: MyTask)

        expect:
        task.name == 'myTask'
    }

    def "try domain container"() {
        given:
        def task = project.task('myTask', type: MyTask) {
            hello {
                myMethod 'my data'
            }
            hiagain {
                myMethod 'other data'
            }
        }

        expect:
        task.getGuy('hello') == 'my data'
        task.getGuy('hiagain') == 'other data'
    }
}
```

The only place I see something similar in the documentation is at the bottom of the [*Chapter 61. Writing Custom Plugins*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html).

This doesn't work, and when I run the test I get this stack trace:

> No signature of method: com.mkobit.gradle.MyTaskTest.hello() is
>   applicable for argument types:
>   (com.mkobit.gradle.MyTaskTest$__spock_feature_0_1_closure1$_closure2)
>   values:
>
> ...

I am not sure how I should go about achieving this, or even if this is the right way to do this.

Is providing a method that contains these on the task better? Then it could look something like:

```groovy
task myTask(type: MyTask) {
    myHellos {
        hello {
            myMethod 'my data'
        }
        hiagain {
            myMethod 'other data'
        }
    }
}
```

But I am still not sure how I would do that.

So basically, how do I add arbitrarily named domain objects to a task?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717135/correct-way-to-configure-gradle-plugin-extensions-with-groups-of-dynamic-objects/33718531#33718531) answer might be useful for you. What's important it's rather not `Task` where such configurations are created but rather extensions per plugin.

Comment: @Opal That answer is definitely helpful. It looks like that answer creates extension objects on the project. Could you do the same with tasks? With the DSL I am trying to provide, it seems like (I'm not sure) that would allow me to do the DSL at the bottom of my question. I want the extension to be specific to the task, and I'm not sure if you can do that so I'll give it a try!

Comment: not sure if it can be done on task instance - suppose yes. Unfortunately can't check this out at the moment since leaving in a few hours for the long weekend. Please keep mu updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717135/correct-way-to-configure-gradle-plugin-extensions-with-groups-of-dynamic-objects/33718531#33718531) provided by [@Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal), I was able to come up with a solution. [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) is [`ExtensionAware`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html), so you can create extensions on the task. Here is how I was able to adapt the above classes to get the DSL I described at the bottom of my question:

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    MyTask() {
        def myExtensionContainer = project.container(MyContainerData)
        extensions.add('myExtension', myExtensionContainer)
    }
}
```

---

```groovy
class MyContainerData {

    String myValue
    String name

    public MyContainerData(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    void myMethod(String s) {
        myValue = s
    }
}
```

---

```groovy
mport org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTaskTest extends Specification {
    def project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()

    def "name test"() {
        given:
        def task = project.task('myTask', type: MyTask)

        expect:
        task.name == 'myTask'
    }

    def "try domain container"() {
        given:
        def task1 = project.task('myTask', type: MyTask) {
            myExtension {
                hello {
                    myMethod 'my data'
                }
                hiagain {
                    myMethod 'other data'
                }
            }
        }
        def task2 = project.task('otherTask', type: MyTask) {
            myExtension {
                myDude {
                    myMethod 'other data'
                }
            }
        }
        expect:
        task1.extensions.myExtension.hello.myValue == 'my data'
        task1.extensions.myExtension.hello.name == 'hello'
        task1.extensions.myExtension.hiagain.myValue == 'other data'
        task1.extensions.myExtension.hiagain.name == 'hiagain'
        task2.extensions.myExtension.myDude.myValue == 'other data'
    }
}
```